# Data Modeling with NoSQL (DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, data-modeling, nosql

Coming from a SQL background, I understand the high-level concepts on NoSQL but still having troubles trying to translating some basic usage scenario.  I am hoping someone can help.

My application simply record a location, a timestamp, and tempature for every second of the day.  So we end up having 3 basic columns:

> 1) location 
>       2) timestamp 
>       3) and temperature

(All field are numbers and I'm storing the timestamp as an ***epoch*** for easy range querying)

I setup dynamodb with the location as the primary key, and the timestamp as the sortkey and temp as an attribute.  This results in a composite key on location and timestamp which allows each location to have its own unique timestamp but not allow any individual location to have more than one identical timestamp.

Now comes the real-world queries:

1. Query each site for a time range ***(Works fine)***
2. Query for any particular time-range return all temps for all locations ***(won't work)***

So how would you account for the 2nd scenario?  This is were I get hung up... Is this were we get into secondary indexes and things like that? For those of you smarter than me, how would you deal with this?

Thanks in advance for you help!
-D

Comment: Query a time range and include all locations (won't work) - can be any time range?

Answer (score 1):

you cant query for range of values in dynamodb. you can query for a range of values (range keys) that belongs to a certain value (hash key)

its not matter if this is table key, local secondary index key, or global secondary index (secondary index are giving you another query options..)

lets back to your scenario:

if timestamp is in seconds and you want to get all records between 2 timestamps then you can add another field 'min_timestamp'.
this field can be your global secondary hash key, and timestamp will be your global secondary range key.

now you can get all records that logged in a certain minute.
if you want a range of minutes, then you need to perform X queries (if X its the range of minutes)

you can also add another field 'hour_timestamp' (that hash key contains all records in a certain hour) and goes on... - but this approach is very dangerous - you going to update many records with the same hash key in the same point of time, and you can get many throughput errors...

Comment: So what would you use for partition key and sort key if you we would want to use the timestamp as an attribute for range lookup and return all locations?

Comment: Also, I wan't going to breakout units in the timestamp as they can already be accounted for in the epoch.  So if I wanted to lookup values for today between 8am and 9am I can just query the attribute values between 1460534400 and 1460538000.

Comment: Correction in the comment above... I don't want to breakout units in the timestamp as they can already be accounted for in the epoch. So if I wanted to lookup values for today between 8am and 9am I can just query the attribute values between 1460534400 and 1460538000.

Comment: @user2259963 sorry, didnt understand your question, can you be more clear?